# foreign package but with non italicized \ie and \eg

Tags: typography

I would like to continue using the foreign package, which italicizes (through emph)  foreign words such as "i.e." and "e.g." . However, it is quite common to not italicize "i.e.", "e.g.", "et al", "etc." in English (perhaps also "cf."). Is there a way to specify this using the foreign package?

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand\ie{\textup{i.e.}}`?

Comment: I tend to use `\makeatletter \newcommand*\ie{\textup{i.e.}\@ifnextchar.{\@gobble}{}} \makeatother` which lets you write `\ie. this and, \ie, that` rather than `\ie{} this and, \ie, that`.

Comment: @Manuel Why not `\newcommand*\ie{\textup{i.e.}\xspace}`?  (using the [`xspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package)

Comment: @HenriMenke Never used `xspace`, and I don't think I needed it (apart from the fact that it's been un-recommended in many ocassions). But yes, that works too. But the pro of my command is that you can use `\eg. this` and you don't get “e.g..”, and to me it feels more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want *none* of the abbreviations provided by `foreign` to be in italics, just do

```
\renewcommand{\foreignabbrfont}{}
```

after `\usepackage{foreign}`. If only selected abbreviations should not be in italics, you have to change their definitions manually. For instance, if `\ie` and `\eg` are to be printed in the same font as the context, add

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\ie{%
  \UKUS@comma{i.e}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\eg{%
  \UKUS@comma{e.g}%
}
\makeatother
```

Look in `foreign.sty` to retrieve the definitions.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to manually do as you described but the list of non-italiziced foreign words are so long that I just went with the simpler option of `\renewcommand{\foreignabbrfont}{}`. See the list here: https://grammarpartyblog.com/2012/02/23/when-to-italicize-foreign-words-and-phrases/ 
The command `\renewcommand{\foreignabbrfont}{}` will successfully work for the latin abbreviations, but will not un-italicize other foreign words such as `\ala`

Comment: In addition, this will not work for other commonly un-italicized words such as `\adhoc` and so forth.